# Unable to decrypt the data in java which is encrypted in webcrypto api

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, webcrypto-api, block-cipher

I am generating key pair in java and encrypted some plain text in
webcrypto API by using the public key. I am getting encrypted data is
in Uint8Array format and trying to decrypt with my private key in java
stand alone.

**Java Code:**

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class RSAOAEP {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

    byte[] input = "{\"userid\":\"raj1242\",\"appid\":\"1234\",\"tenentid\":\"4567\",\"sessionid\":\"session1234567\"}".getBytes();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding", "BC");
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");

    generator.initialize(4096, random);

    KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
    Key pubKey = pair.getPublic();

    Key privKey = pair.getPrivate();

    System.out.println("privateKey: "+privKey);
    System.out.println("publicKey: "+pubKey);

    //Need to assign value from webcrpto api encrypted data
    byte[] cipherText= {};
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
    byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
    System.out.println("plain : " + new String(plainText));
  }
}
```

**Webcrypto API Code for encrypt data:**

```
window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    {
        name: "RSA-OAEP",
        //label: Uint8Array([...]) //optional
    },
    publicKey, //from java generateKey 
    data //ArrayBuffer of data you want to encrypt
)
.then(function(encrypted){
    //returns an ArrayBuffer containing the encrypted data
    console.log(new Uint8Array(encrypted));
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: And ...? There's no question here.

Comment: How to convert Uint8array to byte array to use in java for decrypt the data?

Answer (score 0):

All of Java primitives are signed. To convert Uint8 to byte you can do the following. Although the values may seem not equal but chiper algorithms works on bit representations.
Values from 0 to 127 are equal on both signed and unsigned versions

```
            Signed byte value   Unsigned byte value
0000 0001  =  1                 1
...
0111 1111  =  127               127
```

After 128 values change like this

```
              Signed byte value  Unsigned byte value
1000 0000   = -128                128
1000 0001   = -127                129
1000 0011   = -125                131
.....
1111 1111   = -1                  255
```

So we can write code to convert unsigned values bit representations to signed byte.

```
    // You should read uint8 value to short and then do the conversion
    public byte covertToSignedByte (short unit8Value){
        byte byteValue ;
        if(unit8Value <= 127){
           byteValue = (byte) unit8Value; // it is same up to 127
        }
        else {
           byteValue = (byte)(unit8Value- 256); // after 128 we can substract 256 to get the signed bit representation
        }
        return byteValue;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for code sharing. I tried the approach what you suggested to convert unsigned values to signed bytes. But when I am going with cipher getting exception ** Exception in thread "main" org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.util.BadBlockException: unable to decrypt block **

Comment: @rajasekharpippalla I dont know much about bouncycastle, but are you sure your private key is correct. It looks like it is randomly generated.

Comment: private key is correct, because i am able to decrypt some data which is encrypted in java. but i am facing issue while trying to decrypt data which is encrypted in webcrypto api

Comment: @rajasekharpippalla Question has base64 tag, Are You decoding base64 string before giving it to chiper in java side. It is just a wild guess.

Comment: I didn't use base64 for encode or decode in java. I have seen some kind of solutions for encryption and decryption between java and webcrypto api with base64. I tried those but no luck

Comment: i have seen byte in java is equal data type to int8Array in type script. I am taking ** new int8Array(encrypted) ** in webcrypto api and initializing byte array in java with content what I am getting from webcrypto. But getting error like  ** java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: too much data for RSA block ** .

Comment: @rajasekharpippalla You should ask new question about your new problem, probably get answer much faster.